# want to put ubuntu on a samsung 700z3 running windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, uefi

Wy question is:
I want Ubuntu on my laptop and get rid of Windows.
I had Ubuntu before and I love it.
How can I bypass the UEFI so I can get Ubuntu on this laptop so I can be back on what I love?

Using Ubuntu to get my work done.
I have ubuntu on a flashdrive its 12.10.

If there is any questions for the specs please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that recent Samsung laptops have a firmware bug that can brick the computer when it's booted in EFI mode. There's an Ubuntu bug report about this [here,](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1040557) but be aware that it's wider than this. See [Matthew Garrett's blog post about the topic](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/22855.html) for details. Basically, writing enough data to the UEFI storage space, even from Windows, will brick the computer. Thus, the only safe way to use these computers at the moment is to do so entirely in BIOS/legacy/CSM mode. To do this, you'll need to disable EFI support in the firmware, re-install Windows in legacy/BIOS mode (or convert the EFI installation to boot in legacy/BIOS mode, which is likely to be tricky), and install Linux in legacy/BIOS mode. Unfortunately, EFI implementations have completely non-standardized user interfaces, and since I don't own a Samsung, I can't give you directions on how to disable EFI mode and enable legacy/BIOS mode. The best I can suggest is that you enter the firmware setup utility and look for options with promising-sounding names.

On computers without this bug, or if/when Samsung fixes it in a firmware update, you can install Ubuntu in EFI mode fairly simply. You'll need Ubuntu 12.10 or later for Secure Boot support or you'll need to disable Secure Boot in the firmware, but in theory it should install pretty much the same way it would install on any other computer. In practice, there are quite a few EFI-specific bugs, but they tend to vary from one computer to another. Thus, there's no way to answer the question as stated without writing a *very* long response. The best I can say here is to follow the usual Ubuntu installation instructions and, if you run into problems, post a more specific question. I must reiterate, though, that installing Ubuntu in EFI mode on a Samsung laptop is *very* risky, and I do *not* recommend you try.